# How to replace a 'buy' button, with a 'notify me' button? I'm using the platform 'big cartel' for a clothing brand

Tags: web, notify, bigcartel

How to replace the 'buy' button, with a 'notify me' button? I'm using the platform 'big cartel' for a clothing brand. The products aren't ready yet for sale, and instead of people looking at an item and leaving, I want to provide the option for an interested customer to be notified when they the item is finally ready. So the idea is instead of the usual 'buy' button, or a 'sold out', 'coming soon' note, there is a 'notify me when available' button. When clicked this then brings up an option to provide an email in order to be notified.

I'm fairly illiterate with coding, so have yet to approach this on my own, need some indication of a direction first.